# What Data Structures can't be implemented in C but in Java?

Tags: data-structures

Can anyone tell me what data structure i can't use in C language but in Java.
Can anyone tell me what data structure i can't use in C language but in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Any data structure can be build in any language. But, java already have predefined collection of data structures. For example, java already have collections for LinkedLists,HashMaps,Trees... But in C, you have to implement on your own if you need.